# Best way to parse raw query params in scala

Tags: scala, uri, akka-http

I currently using `akka-http`, and I trying to parse `Referer` header which contains raw uri string. How can I parse query parameters from it, in the 
case where they are not encoded?

Here the example of the uri:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.Uri

Uri("https://foo.bar?b=x y").query().toMap
Uri("https://foo.bar?a=%%_1_%%").query().toMap
```

Both of them will throw `IllegalUriException`. Is there an elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to import this it should get **"akka.http.javadsl.model.headers.RawRequestURI"** 
 let me know. i am searching

Comment: not exactly. From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/common/uri-model.html#obtaining-the-raw-request-uri). This is a header which using for putting "raw" incoming URI to this header, and what I need - it is to parse raw uri query to map.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to bring in a separate library, scala-uri can do this with its `NoopDecoder`

But be careful! If the URL contains a raw `&` that was originally percent encoded, it will be interpreted as separating a new query parameter

```
import io.lemonlabs.uri._
import io.lemonlabs.uri.config._
import io.lemonlabs.uri.decoding._

implicit val c = UriConfig(decoder = NoopDecoder)

Url.parse("https://foo.bar?b=x y").query.params
// val res4: Vector[(String, Option[String])] = Vector((b,Some(x y))

Url.parse("https://foo.bar?a=%%_1_%%").query.params
// val res3: Vector[(String, Option[String])] = Vector((a,Some(%%_1_%%)))
```

https://github.com/theon/scala-uri#url-percent-decoding